# How to solve an optimization problem with bilinear constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given $A_1,A_2,A_3\in\mathbb{H}^n$ such that $A_1\succ0$, how to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{k\geq1,X\in\mathbb{H^n}}{\text{minimize}} & k\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}\Big(\big(A_1+(k+k^{-1})A_2\big)X\Big)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(A_3X)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\succeq0,\end{array}

where "$X\succeq 0$" means that $X$ is positive semi-definite and $\mathbb{H}^n$ is the set of all $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices.

---

For $k\geq1$, minimizing $\lambda$ is equivalent to minimizing $k+k^{-1}$, thus we can rewrite above problem:

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{k\geq1,X\in\mathbb{H^n}}{\text{minimize}} & k\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}\Big(\big(A_1+kA_2\big)X\Big)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(A_3X)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\succeq0,\end{array}

the only bilinear term is $kA_2X$. Is there any way to handle this in a convex way, so that global minimum is achieved?

Currently, I solve the problem for fixed $k$ and if the problem is feasible then keep decreasing the $k$. I don't think this is the best way.

---

EDIT: After reading some existing questions, I think we can use bisection method. I wrote a program based on the description here: [bisection method](https://yalmip.github.io/example/decayrate/) and it converges quite fast. But I am not sure how to show that it converges to global minimum, not a local minimum?

Is this problem quasi-convex?